# How to scan THREE items connected by "and"s?

Tags: conjunctions, commas, lists

I found a sentence in the *Reader's Choice* (5th Edition, by Sandra Silberstein, Barbara K. Dobson and Mark A. Clarke) that has three items connected by "and"s in it:

> These efforts can assure the survival of wildlife that otherwise would not continue to exist. I also may be that tourism can help strengthen local cultures by encouraging awareness of traditions and ceremonies. Historic building thrive on tourism. **These cultural locations enjoy great success with the money and attention and respect brought by tourism**.

Which one, in the following, is a better or (more) correct way to parse the relationship of the three things and why?

A. "with the (money and attention and respect) brought by tourism"
B. "with {the money and (attention and respect)} brought by tourism"
C. "with {(the money and attention) and respect} brought by tourism"
D. "enjoy {(great success with the money) and (attention and respect)} brought by tourism"
E. OR any other syntax scan.

Grammatically, 'X & Y & Z' should be "X, Y, and Z'.
However, the definition of "and" as a conjunction from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary is:

> When "and" is used in common phrases connecting **two** things or people that are closely linked, the determiner is not usually repeated before the second.

But this sentence has "THREE" things.

What do you think about that?

Comment: You only need one 'and' - These cultural locations enjoy great success with the money, attention, and respect brought by tourism."

Comment: Which one is the coRRect syntax? OR the original sentence I quoted is incorrect?

Comment: You can emphasize something in English using two ands between three items. I like swimming and sailing and surfing. That is just fine, as a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Three things contribute independently to the great success: money, attention, respect.

I think the use of "with" here awkward.

I think poorly written sentences are not good ones for practicing how to parse English.

Comment: > I think the use of "with" here awkward.
- What is a better/best preposition instead "with"?

>I think poorly written sentences are not good ones for practicing how to parse English.
- Then, how do I need to change?